# How to set Metatag fb:pages correctly to enable link editing for one page with multiple channels?

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

Facebook doesn't enable link editing by default anymore. Pages now have to be validated with the meta tag `fb:pages` to fight click baiting. But how to do it properly? If a Website has multiple Facebook channels would it be enough to add the meta tag fb:pages with the content value of the main channel or does every channel require it's own meta tag?

So for example would adding this be sufficient:

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="<channel_id_of_main_channel>">
```

Or is it necessary that there is a meta tag for every channel on each page to enable link editing on all channels? For example:

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="<channel_id_of_main_channel>">
<meta property="fb:pages" content="<other_channel_id>">
<meta property="fb:pages" content="<another_channel_id>">
```

The thing is that articles (with unique URLs) can be published in different channels. And in every channel link editing should be possible. Would that be accomplished by one of these code snippets or what is the proper way to do that? Anyone could share their experience please?

And another question - is the meta tag `fb:page_id` obsolete? The last articles I found about it were from 2010 or something. Modern pages still use it but I'm not sure if it's still needed. The page_id was the same as the channel id.

Comment: hi do you know if is there more info about the fb:pages tag? I cant find any

Comment: Same. I can't find how to get fb:pages meta tag

Answer (score 13):

The answer to this was simple - one metatag with all ids have to be in the head section of each page on a website:

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="<channel1_id>, <channel2_id>, <channel3_id>, ...">
```

P.S.: The fb:page_id metatag is deprecated.

Comment: Example: `<meta property="fb:pages" content="123,456,789">`

Comment: This seems to be out of date. Do you know what the current solution is?

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew: I don't know about any changes. Our Social Media team didn't complain so far so I guess it's still working like this. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I'll try it then. The weird thing is that it doesn't appear in any documentation anymore

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work. Moreover it's been officially deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637678/how-to-i-associate-a-web-page-with-a-facebook-page-is-fbpages-deprecated/58653318#58653318