# How to I associate a web page with a Facebook page? Is fb:pages deprecated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

On a web page, I include

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="123...">
```

as well as various open graph info. I created that Facebook "page" with that number recently.

When the link is shared on Facebook og:image etc. works, but there is no connection to the Facebook "page" I tried to link. Instead, there is an "i" in the top right corner of the share which gives an information box About This Website which says "Facebook Page: Not found for ". (I have put the url in the [sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) first and rescraped the url it there.)

I see that there are ways to verify your ownership of a whole domain in the "Business manager" ([facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification), but there it says:

> You can still add Open Graph tags to your website to indicate ownership—this does not require the use of Business Manager. You can find more information about implementing the fb:pages tag in the Open Graph - Object Properties documentation.

So I think fb:pages is supposed to work, and I think it's supposed to work the way I did. Unfortunately, the link from that quote goes to irrelevant documentation now. Also, Facebook's Sharing Debugger shows `fb:app_id` among the Open Graph properties it found on the page.

On the other hand, there are other docs where only `fb:app_id` is mentioned. So is it still possible to without making an app or include more Facebook interactivity on your web pages to just state inside a web page which Facebook "page" it should be associated with? (Like I thought `fb_pages` would work.)

Comment: Not sure if that is supposed to work that way for just any tiny Facebook page … it might be you need to get to a certain “size” first.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's it. Then it would be good to at least find some current documentation that states that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook showing page not found when sharing link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077743/facebook-showing-page-not-found-when-sharing-link)

Comment: What similarity between the questions do you see, @VicSeedoubleyew?

Comment: @pst I am not sure I understand your question, because I am not sure why it is not obvious. Have you read the other question? If so, can you please explain why you don't see any similarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Open Graph - Object Properties documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph#standard), "Effective May 1st, 2019, all newly published Open Graph stories will render as a plain link share in newsfeed". The [Open Graph Markup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) also no longer has the fb:pages meta tag. Some basic tags, like og:image, are still documented.

That's... a decision I don't understand.

Comment: Thank you for this contribution. While it makes it clear that Facebook has dropped `fb:pages`, I am pretty sure they have replaced it with something else, since otherwise it wouldn't be showing this message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077743/facebook-showing-page-not-found-when-sharing-link